# Individual points tranform editing doesnt work when selecting face loops

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, transform-orientation

I am trying to scale an entire object on the faces individual normal axis, by using normal transform origin and the individual origins pivot point in edit mode. This method works fine if I select only a few faces, but when I ALT-select the entire face loop, it stops working, and automatically uses a median point pivot point instead. Pictures attached:
[image]

It works when only selecting a few faces

[image]

but not when selecting the entire loop. Is there a max number if faces you can select or something? Why is this not working?

Comment: The "individual origins" are the median values of "islands", not of faces.  It uses the individual face normals in the first picture because each *contiguous* selection is an individual face.  In the second picture, the entire selection is contiguous.  Scaling by individual face normal for contiguous selections doesn't make sense, because adjustments to one face affect adjacent faces.  But you can use a checker deselect operation to get every other face selected and do an operation on those.  You will see then how it affects unselected faces as well.

Comment: I'm not even sure in which direction you want to scale individually when selecting the whole loop... in the screenshots I see those blue lines, looking like you want to scale in the face normal (which is the local Z of the face) direction. However, on a planar face, the Z dimension is 0. Scaling by x is x · 0 = 0, so scaling in this direction makes only sense if you had a pivot point outside the face like the 3D cursor (and the lines in the first image look like that).

Comment: And scaling in all directions with individual origins as pivot points would scale the faces in X and Y direction - but if you want to do it on the complete loop, what should happen to adjacent faces if they are both scaled up or down? Did you really mean scale or move in normal direction? And if you want to scale them away from e.g. the 3D cursor, then you need the 3D cursor as pivot point and not individual origins...

Comment: @Nathan that appears to be an answer. Please post it as one.

Comment: @TheLabCat My decisions to post as an answer or as a comment are not made in ignorance; they are made on the basis of my experience on this site, as well as my own comfort in whether the detail I am willing to provide is enough to qualify as an answer.  Frequently, the perfect is the enemy of the good on SE, but I want to help people out anyways.  If you feel that what I said is a good answer, please post it as one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nathan stated in the comments:

The "individual origins" are the median values of "islands", not of faces. It uses the individual face normals in the first picture because each contiguous selection is an individual face. In the second picture, the entire selection is contiguous. Scaling by individual face normal for contiguous selections doesn't make sense, because adjustments to one face affect adjacent faces. But you can use a checker deselect operation to get every other face selected and do an operation on those. You will see then how it affects unselected faces as well.